# Two ways to plot a triangle

Tags: graphics, polygons

Writing:

```
L = 1;
xc = 1;
yc = 1;
θ = Pi/6;

plot1 = ContourPlot[
   Max[(x - xc) Sin[θ + 0 Pi/3] - (y - yc) Cos[θ + 0 Pi/3],
       (x - xc) Sin[θ + 2 Pi/3] - (y - yc) Cos[θ + 2 Pi/3],
       (x - xc) Sin[θ + 4 Pi/3] - (y - yc) Cos[θ + 4 Pi/3]] == L/(2 Sqrt[3]),
       {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50];

plot2 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], 
                  FaceForm[None], 
                  Rotate[RegularPolygon[{xc, yc}, L/Sqrt[3], 3], θ]}];

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

I get:

[image]

and I just can not understand the reason why the two graphics do not coincide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If center of rotation not be set up , the triangle will rotated about the center of its bounding box .

(´・ω・`)

```
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], FaceForm[None], 
      Rotate[RegularPolygon[{xc, yc}, L/Sqrt[3], 3], \[Theta], {1, 1}]}]
```

Comment: If center of rotation not be set up ,the triangle will rotated about the center of its bounding box .(´・ω・`)